# Sending ephemeral responses to a specific user discord js (only you can see this message)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to send an ephemeral response (only you can see this message) to a user specified by a command, using discord.js

Comment: Ephemeral messages can only be sent as a reply to an ongoing interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send an ephemeral message to a specific user, that user needs to be the one triggering the interaction.

You **cannot** send an ephemeral message to a random user.

If you just want to reply to an interaction , you can do it by using:

```
// assuming "i" is your interaction
i.reply({ content: "This message is only for your sweet eyes", ephemeral: true });
```